# How to do a "is_a", "typeof" or instanceof in QML?

Tags: javascript, qml

I want to run through a list of QML components and choose one type:

```
for (var i = 0; i < controls.children.length; ++i) {
     if ( typeof (controls.children[i].height) == "QDeclarativeRectangle")
     {
        // do stuff
     }
}
```

How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use **typeof** for this directly because it will always return you **'object'** as a type of any QML element. There are several alternatives however that you could use. One is setting the **objectName** of the each element to its type and check that in your loop or define a property and check for that property. This will require a bit more work but you could create your qml element that has this property and than use it wherever you need it.
Here is a sample code:

```
Rectangle {
  id: main
  width: 300; height: 400

  Rectangle {
    id: testRect
    objectName: "rect"
    property int typeId: 1
  }

  Item {
    id: testItem
    objectName: "other"
  }

  Component.onCompleted: {
    for(var i = 0; i < main.children.length; ++i)
    {
        if(main.children[i].objectName === "rect")
        {
            console.log("got one rect")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("non rect")
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < main.children.length; ++i)
    {
        if(main.children[i].typeId === 1)
        {
            console.log("got one rect")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("non rect")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Since Qt 5.10, you can finally use `instanceOf` to check whether a variable is of a certain QML type, see ["QML Support for Enum and InstanceOf Type Checks"](https://felgo.com/updates/felgo-2-15-0-qt-5-10-qt-creator-4-5-support-firebase-data-structures-and-queries#qt-5-10-qml-enum-instanceof).

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0

App {
  // two QML items, used for type checking
  Item { id: testItem }
  Rectangle { id: testRect }

  // function to check wheter an item is a Rectangle
  function isRectangle(item) {
    return item instanceof Rectangle
  }

  // type check example
  Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("testItem is Rectangle? " + isRectangle(testItem))
    console.log("testRect is Rectangle? " + isRectangle(testRect))
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.14 and this doesn't seem to work. I want to find the `Transform` component in an entity, so I have a code like `for(var i = 0; i < entity.components.length; i++) { console.log("component", i, ":", entity.components[i], "instance of Transform?", entity.components[i] instanceof Transform) }` but it prints: *component 2 : Qt3DCore::QTransform(0x7fd85a4279b0) instance of Transform? false*

Comment: For Qt3DCore::QTransform you can just use entity.components[i].toString().includes("Transform"). It's not the fastest thing, but it works.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another approach using toString() (which might not be portable to the future version of QML):

```
function qmltypeof(obj, className) { // QtObject, string -> bool
  // className plus "(" is the class instance without modification
  // className plus "_QML" is the class instance with user-defined properties
  var str = obj.toString();
  return str.indexOf(className + "(") == 0 || str.indexOf(className + "_QML") == 0;
}

...

for (var i = 0; i < controls.children.length; ++i) {
   if (qmltypeof(controls.children[i].height, "QDeclarativeRectangle"))
   {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice trick. I would modify the return statement for convenience:

`return str.indexOf(className + "(") == 0 || str.indexOf(className + "_QML") == 0 || qmltypeof(obj, "QQuick" + className);`

Comment: Even if it's not portable, `toString` is great for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this thread is 2 yrs old but perhaps my answer could help someone out there.

For me, it was good enough use `JSON.stringify()` to compare QML elements.  Of course, if two different elements have exactly the same properties and values, this would give you false positive.  (eg when one element is on top of another with same color, x, y, etc)

toString() did not work for me since I've created many instances from same base component.  Setting *objectName* to every instance would have been a bit too much for my use case.