# How to get base class of item in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

Is there any way to get item class in `QML`? I know about `objectName` and `id` etc. but it looks a bit strange and not so comfortable. This is what i need:

```js
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
}
TextField {
    id: textField
}

function getValue(item) {
    switch(item.???) {   //what property can I use here?
        case 'ComboBox':
            return item.model.get(item.currentIndex).value;
        case 'TextField':
            return item.text;
    }
}
```

using `objectName` as described in lots of articles over the Internet might be ambiguous and excessive, for example:

```js
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    objectName: "ComboBox"
}
TextField {
    id: textField
    objectName: "ComboBox" /// oops!!
}

function getValue(item) {
    switch(item.objectName) {  
        case 'ComboBox':
            return item.model.get(item.currentIndex).value;
        case 'TextField':
            return item.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very likely that this kind of information is erased after parsing because these names are only names of files where components are declared....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can only be done from C++.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also stucked on the same problem.
The following reply could be a good workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13928333/1994341.

That is to say: for each item you set the property "objectName" with a unique name. objectName is the only property of [QtObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-qtobject.html#objectName-prop), which is inherited by each QML item.

According to me this is a miss, however QML is a great tool.

Comment: you might flesh it out, as it stands it's a link only answer and will likely be deleted.

Comment: As far as I can judge, I'd say yes :)

Comment: Thank's for you advice then !