# How to get id of child in qml

Tags: qt, debugging, qml

When I tried to get children ID's slightly modifying this http://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch01/index.html example

```
// animate.qml

import QtQuick 2.0

Item 
{
    id: root
    width: background.width
    height: background.height
    property string information: "this is root"

    property int rotationStep: 45

    Image {
        id: background
        source: "images/background.png"
    }

    Image {
        id: pole
        property string information: "this is pole"
        x: (root.width - width)/2+2
        y: root.height - height
        source: "images/pole.png"
    }

    Image {
        id: pinwheel
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "images/pinwheel.png"
        property string information: "this is pinweel"
        // visible: false
        Behavior on rotation {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 125 }
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: blur
        opacity: 0
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "images/blur.png"
         property string information: "this is blur"
        // visible: false
        Behavior on rotation {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 125 }
        }
        Behavior on opacity {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 125 }
        }

    }

    // M1>>
    focus: true
    Keys.onLeftPressed: {
        blur.opacity = 0.8
        pinwheel.rotation -= root.rotationStep
        blur.rotation -= root.rotationStep
    }
    Keys.onRightPressed: {
        blur.opacity = 0.5
        pinwheel.rotation += root.rotationStep
        blur.rotation += root.rotationStep
    }
    Keys.onReleased: {
        blur.opacity = 0
    }

    Keys.onSpacePressed:
    {
        for (var i=0; i<root.children.length; ++i)
            console.info(root.children[i].information)
    }

    Keys.onDeletePressed:
    {
        for (var i=0; i<root.children.length; ++i)
            console.info(root.children[i].id)
    }


    // <<M1
}
```

Unfortunately  pressing Delete key gives me an error:

```
qml: undefined
qml: undefined
qml: undefined
qml: undefined
```

as opposed to pressing spacebar:

```
qml: undefined
qml: this is pole
qml: this is pinweel
qml: this is blur
```

Why this script returns undefined id's ?

I need to traverse some objects and be able to tell what is what - so I need to know how to traverse root tree to get id's of its childs and their object types.

Unfortunately I was unable to print the most trival id's and had to add some simple property to get it done but this means a lot of work in real life project since every object needs information property :(

So to reiterate:

1. Why the id's in this example are undefined?
2. How to traverse object tree using qml and print its id's and types ?

Comment: I've had a similar question to ask. Can you edit your question in order to get an explanation about why it's not possible to access the value of the `id` of an object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id is not an ordinary object property, so it is undefined when you try to assess it through js. And qml doesn't provide operators like `typeof`. So you need to add `type` or `objectname` property manually. I would consider subclassing `Image` and adding `type`. Ref: [How to do a "is_a", "typeof" or instanceof in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923794/how-to-do-a-is-a-typeof-or-instanceof-in-qml)

```
Item 
{
id: root

Image {
    id: background
    type: "image"
}

Image {
    id: pole
    type: "image"
}
function iter(){
     for(var i = 0; i < root.children.length; ++i)
         if(root.children[i].type==="image"){
         //balabala
         }
     }
}
}
```

Comment: But why id is not provided? I can understand why it should be read-only , but what is the reason in terms of application engineering not to provide id for developer?

Comment: @user2614242 The `id` is not a real property. From the docs: "While it may look like an ordinary property, the `id` attribute is not an ordinary property attribute, and special semantics apply to it; for example, it is not possible to access `myTextInput.id` in the above example."